# what is best choice for saving download links and some attributes (database or file)?

Tags: json, xml, database, hyperlink, download

i am working on a project that it stores movies download links and some attributes for each download link like: (quality, encoder, codec and subtitle link)

in this case may be each movie has more than one download link, for example a movie has 2 codec and each codec has 4 encoders that each encoder has 3 quality and 3 different subtitle link.
so i want to know save them in file or in database? which one is best way?
and if the choice is file, then json is good or xml?

another thing is that i want to work with it using C#!

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my self will advice of database 
because from data base you can handle your data easily 
while saving data to file and handling like edit,update etc is some difficult in complex scenario.
You can also get backup of your db as a small sql file.
But if you have no such complex scenario you can use file for saving data.
for file saving i will recommend json for its ease.xml is good but have complexity.
please also read the below link

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190482/why-use-a-database-instead-of-just-saving-your-data-to-disk